# MVC 6 API Multiple Parameters

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following API, which takes care of updating items in the database:

```
    [Route("update")]
    [HttpPost("")]
    public JsonResult UpdateRecords([FromBody]ICollection<ShoppingItemViewModel> vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var items = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ShoppingItem>>(vm);

                //update database
                _repository.UpdateValues(items, User.Identity.Name);

                return Json(null);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Then under my Angular code I am executing this `POST` method like following:

```
    $scope.SaveChanges = function () {
        $http.post("/api/items/update", $scope.items)
            .then(function (response) {
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.errorMessage = "Error occured: " + err;
            }).finally(function () {

            });

    };
```

What I would like to do, is to introduce new parameters to my initial `UpdateRecords` function, where some of them are optional. Then depending on the inserted parameters my procedure would do different things.

What I have tried to do is to change my function like following (example):

```
public JsonResult UpdateRecords([FromBody]ICollection<ShoppingItemViewModel> vm, [FromBody]bool EraseOldItems)
```

and under my Angular App:

```
$http.post("/api/items/update", {vm:$scope.items, EraseOldItems: true})
```

or even

```
$http.post("/api/items/update", {'vm':$scope.items, 'EraseOldItems': true})
```

but I could not get the code to work (my parameters were all the time null).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body.
>
> ```
> // Caution: Will not work!    
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```
>
> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a
>   non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

You can pass a request object that contains other objects:

```
public class Request
{
    public ICollection<ShoppingItemViewModel> vm { get; set; }
    public bool eraseOldItems { get; set; }
}
```

And then your action:

```
[Route("update")]
[HttpPost("")]
public JsonResult UpdateRecords([FromBody]Request request){ ... }
```